# Use velocity.js with webpack

Tags: jquery, webpack, velocity.js

I'm trying to use some parts of `materialize-css`, `js`, some of these parts depend on velocity and some other chunks of code that I have depend on `jQuery`. I'm using `webpack` to build it all.

requiring velocity is not working for me, I still get a `.velocity is not a function`. I use `ProvidePlugin` to inject jQuery (installed with npm) where `$` or `jQuery` are used, and this is working nice.

```
plugins: [
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: "jquery",
    jQuery: "jquery",
  })
]
```

However looks like velocity is not being able to inject `velocity` method into jQuery. I've also tried:

```
module: {
  loaders: [
    {
      test: /jquery\.js$/,
      loader: "expose?jQuery!expose?$"
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you look in velocity.js's node module, it uses `window.jQuery`
you should try adding `window.jQuery` instead to the webpack ProvidePlugin

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: "jquery",
        jQuery: "jquery",
        "window.jQuery": "jquery"
    })
]
```