# Velocity.js, webpack and $.Velocity.RunSequence

Tags: jquery, webpack, velocity.js

I have the Velocity.js library working within a webpack environment on a basic level, however when I try to call the $.Velocity.RunSequence function I'm getting an error that: `$.Velocity.RunSequence is not a function`.

I'm pretty sure this is to do with the way I'm importing the Velocity and jQuery libraries, however even following the docs on http://velocityjs.org/#dependencies (using *Module Loader: Browserify* section) doesn't fix the issue. Using Velocity animations on a basic level (ie. not as a sequence) works fine.

### webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {

  entry: {
    filename: './index.js'
  },

  output: {
    path: path.resolve( __dirname, 'dist' ),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },

  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx$/,
        exclude: '/node_modules/',
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: [ 'es2015' ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    // Uglify
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),

    // Extract HTML & CSS
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ template: './src/index.html' }),

    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/35884552
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery',
      'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
    })
  ]
};
```

### app.jsx

```
import 'velocity-animate';

const $svgRect  = $( '#svg-rect' ),
      $svgElem  = $( '#svg-element' );

$(document).ready(function(){

  const svgRectSequence = [
    { e: $svgRect, p: { x: 100, y: 100 }, o: { duration: 2000 } }, 
    { e: $svgRect, p: { x: 100, y: 0 }, o: { duration: 2000 } },
    { e: $svgRect, p: { x: 0, y: 100 }, o: { duration: 2000 } },
    { e: $svgRect, p: { x: 0, y: 0 }, o: { duration: 2000 } }
  ];

  $.Velocity.RunSequence( svgRectSequence );
});
```

Thanks for any help - thinking this could be a lost cause and may need submitting to the Velocity.js maintainers but thought I should check here first.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add the 'velocity-ui-pack' in order to use the RunSequence function. Thread closed.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/velocity-ui-pack